# Verification of regular expression computed from finite automata

Tags: computability, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Here in the given image, our question is to find regular expression from finite automata. I found three answers based on which state I am resolving. Are these answers in the photo correct? If any answer is incorrect then please provide me the correct answer.

[image: Finite automata to regular expression.]

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm for computing a regular expression $R$ from a deterministic finite-state automaton $M$ such that $L(R) = L(M)$. It is covered in any standard course on formal language theory.

Have you used this conversion algorithm? It does not appear to be the case, but it is very difficult to figure out how you have proceeded in coming up with your attempted solution, since you insist on not writing very much.